# How do I only use user specific objects in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have 2 models, one is for `Users`, and the other is for `Medications`. Each user can have many medications. The user can create medications, but can't see medications other users made.

```html
<% @medications.each do |medication| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= medication.name %></td>
        <td><%= medication.user_id %> </td>
```

Obviously this code doesn't do what I want, but how can I modify the first part to be a conditional that only works if `current_user.id == medication.user_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option1: In your controller, fetch only the current user's medications.

```
# user model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :medications # this needs to be in place
end

# in controller action that is rendering your view
@medications = current_user.medications
```

Option2: In your view, skip medications that don't have the current user's ID in their `user_id` column:

```
# view
<% @medications.each do |med| %>
  <% next if (med.user_id != current_user.id) %>
  <% # more code %>
<% end %>
```

And if you're showing parts of the medication based on the current user, then obviously:

```
# view
<% @medications.each do |med| %>
  <%= medication.name # example %>
  <% next if (med.user_id != current_user.id) %>
  <%= medication.reason # example %>
<% end %>
```

Unless you need to display other medications / other info as well, I'd go with Option1.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) in your medication model so that you can find the current users medication and use it in other places as well:

```
   scope :users_medication, ->(current_user) { where user_id: current_user.id}
```

Then in your view call the class method you just defined on the Medication class and pass it the current user:

```
<% Medication.users_medication(current_user).each do |medication| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= medication.name %></td>
        <td><%= medication.user_id %> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @medications = @user.medications
end
```

This will display only the medications of that particular user only